# SSIS - Sending a mail with the name of the task that failed

Tags: email, error-handling, ssis, parent-child, ssis-2012

Let's suppose I've got this scenario. A parent package that contains two children . The child package 1 and 2. The execution of the first one is successful, but the second one fails.
[image]

I need to send a message that will report a failure in the execution of the entire process, but at the same time I need to identify the child package that went wrong inside the message.

How can I get the name of this execute package task from the parent package?

Answer (score 2):

You can put a script task in the failure constraint of each of the two Child Packages that sets a string variable with the name of the child package, and then reference that variable in your email.

Or you could look into using the OnError event handler and parse the inner exception for the object name where the error occurred.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I´ve been looking for information about this. On the parent package I've created an OnError event for child package 2, but the question is, where is this error saved. I mean, I looked the system variables to see if there was present something like ErrorMessage. But I did see nothing similar. Could you please tell me if you know a page that explains a little bit more the concept you mention. I am new in this of SSIS.

Comment: I don't know one off the top of my head, but I would start here:   https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=ssis+onerror+&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=ssis+onerror+event+handler&gs_l=hp..0.0l5j41.0.0.0.5118...........0.EvrnobrCOeo#q=ssis+onerror+event+handler+how+to+retrieve+error+information

Comment: I've been looking at this page https://gqbi.wordpress.com/2014/08/06/ssis-error-handling-and-error-emailing-for-packages/comment-page-1/     But I do not see the errormessage variable he uses. That is why I asked you. Thanks again for your help

Comment: According to this article, http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2007/05/05/handling-multiple-errors-in-ssis/ it's system::errordescription

Comment: Thanks Tab. I have implemented the solution.